# Virtual methods not acting virtual

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, virtual

Consider the folowing code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0) : m_n(n) {}

public: 
    virtual int value() const {return m_n;}
    virtual ~A() {}

protected:
    int m_n;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int n = 0) : A(n){}

public:
    virtual int value() const {return m_n + 1;}
};

int main(char* args[])
{
    const A a(1);
    const B b(3);
    const A *x[2] = {&a, &b};
    typedef std::vector<A> V;
    V y;
    y.push_back(a);
    y.push_back(b);
    V::const_iterator i = y.begin();

    std::cout << x[0]->value() << x[1]->value()
        << i->value() << (i+1)->value() << std::endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does that print out `1413`, rather than `1414`? I would expect `value()` to behave as a virtual function even when called like `(i+1)->value();`.

Comment: Can you give the full output of the `cout`-line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the slicing problem in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your vector `V` holds `A` objects, so there is no scope for dynamic dispatch. You are always calling `A::value()`. The `B` part of your objects is sliced away when they are copied into the vector. It is the same as doing this:

```
B b(1);

A a1 = b;  // a1 is an A object, not a B.
a1.value();
```

See [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Answer (score 3):

Because when you do `y.push_back(b);` slicing happens; the `vector` holds objects of type `A`. To make use of polymorphism, you need references or pointers.